# Laravel Backpack Permission Manager Error : Undefined index: model

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I installed the PermissionManager package following the documentation Official.

But, when i add a new user i get an exception : Undefined index: model

My User model is standard (App\Models\User::class) but I can't find a solution...

Thanks

Comment: please show full error exception from your application log

Comment: Share with us 
- your local env: php, laravel, DB, and backpack version.
- your laravel app log

Comment: have you checked config files if correct model name is written there, you need to debug more or add more info so we can help you

Comment: Can you add your UserCrudController's `setup()` method here, please? I suspect your problem is a typo in `setModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my model is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
//use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
//use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    use Notifiable;

    //use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable ;

   // protected $guard = 'web';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I check my configuration files and compare with official documentation, but for me it's OK...

The exception is :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypSJ6.png

[2022-06-27 15:29:20] local.ERROR: Undefined index: model {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: model at E:\laragon\www\lara_boltr\vendor\backpack\crud\src\app\Library\CrudPanel\Traits\FakeFields.php:42)
[stacktrace]

I've checked all files, but i'dont understand where is a mistake
My Backpack version is 5.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).